# Handling Encoding and Decoding using predefined functions is Freemarker Templating language?

Tags: freemarker

Is there a way to handle decoding and encoding using predefined functions in Freemarker Templating Language?

I am trying to encode a string to UTF-8, in Freemarker Templating Language (FTL), are there any predefined functions to do this? From my basic investigation I found there are no functions so far.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "encode a string to <charset>" in a template?

Comment: i meant if my string is "Do you Know me" encoding should be "Do%20you%20Know%20me"  check encoding for other characters at "http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for URL encoding (aka. percent encoding): `${foo?url}`. The charset used depends on the `url_escaping_charset` configuration setting of FreeMarker, so you should set that to `UTF-8`. (You can also specify the charset like `${foo?url('UTF-8')}`, but of course setting this in the configuration is better.)

In the documentation: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_url

Comment: The function works perfectly without a flaw, I believe there is a typo in your  answer guess ${foo?url('UTF-8')}, is that right ?

Comment: Indeed, typo fixed.